# Python and using lxml to find part if a string using lxml html

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a tab that looks like this...

```
<div id="contentDiv_reviewHistoPop_B004HYGU18_4792" style="display:none;">
```

I can use

```
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
el = doc.get_element_by_id('contentDiv_reviewHistoPop_B004HYGU18_4792')
```

to find the tag but how do I use e.g. a wild card to find contentDiv_reviewHistoPop*  that would find the tags that contains a portion of the string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do this...

```
import lxml.etree as ET
from lxml.etree import XMLParser

parser = XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
html = """<html><body><div id="contentDiv_reviewHistoPop_B004HYGU18_4792" style="display:none;"></body></html>"""
tree = ET.fromstring(html, parser)
tmp = list()
for elem in tree.iter():
    if elem.tag == 'div':
        for ii in elem.items():
            if (ii[0].lower() == 'id') and ('contentDiv_reviewHistoPop' in ii[1]):
                tmp.append(elem)
```

`tmp` will contain the list of matching div elements with the matching text.

If you can only use `lxml.html`, then do this...

```
import lxml.html

html = """<html><body><div id="contentDiv_reviewHistoPop_B004HYGU18_4792" style="display:none;"></body></html>"""
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
tmp = list()
for elem in doc.iter():
    if elem.tag == 'div':
        for ii in elem.items():
            if (ii[0].lower() == 'id') and ('contentDiv_reviewHistoPop' in ii[1]):
                tmp.append(elem)
```

Again... tmp will contain the matching tags